# Как правильней сделать сохранение файлов?

Tags: python, python-3.x, sqlite, discord.py, discord-api

Возник вопрос, как лучше сделать сохранение файлов для каждого сервера?
У меня есть пока 1 вариант:

При заходе бота на сервер создавать отдельную папку под его именем и там же бд sqlite3 и например файл для рангов

Есть ли вариант лучше или так тоже подойдёт?

И если возможно можете помочь у меня бот на 1 сервере команды выполняет моментально т.е например удаляет 100 сообщений, а на другом он не может так делать в чём причина?

Comment: Вы уверены, что имели в виду "сохранение файлов для каждого сервера", а не "сохранение файлов для каждого пользователя"?

Comment: Хотя всего и правда для пользователя, но в бд же и настройки сервера хранится будут такие как автороль, или канал настроенный для чего-нибудь.

Comment: А у Вас файлы будут храниться на диске, или в базе данных? И еще - может ли от одного пользователя прийти два разных файла с одинаковы именем?

Comment: Вот насчёт где хранится скорее и там и там поскольку есть некие расширения для проекта.

Comment: Мне кажется, Вам достаточно ОДНОЙ базы данных и по каталогу на пользователя для хранения файлов.

Comment: Насчёт пользователей тоже думал создать папку в папке сервера и в название добавлять его ник и дискриминатор. Если вы про то, что он выйдет и зайдёт, то будет проверка и при выходе файлы о нём удалятся тоже и с сервером

Comment: Можно сказать 1 база как и сейчас) только пока без игроков

Comment: Ладно, тогда оставлю базу и сделаю записи игроков на каждом сервере спасибо. А что насчёт лагов?